# RichFaces: Load different stylesheets based on active SKIN

Tags: css, richfaces, stylesheet, skin

It concerns the following:

1. There is a base `stylesheet.css` for the web site (by using a `<link>` tag).
2. Depending on user is logged in the skin changes through `SkinBean.setSkin("SKIN")` when the user enters some parts of the web site.
3. If the skin changes than also the loaded style sheet should be changed in `stylesheet-alt.css`.

Is there a quick and simple solution for changing the style sheet depending on used skin in RichFaces?

I will be glad if someone helps.

(This question is not about how to change the skin in RichFaces in general)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<a4j:loadStyle>` instead of `<link>` tag and use `rendered` attribute as below.

```
<a4j:loadStyle src="stylesheet.css" rendered="#{myBean.booleanProperty}"/>
<a4j:loadStyle src="stylesheet-alt.css" rendered="#{!myBean.booleanProperty}"/>
```